# Google API Service Account and nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, service-accounts

I want to be able to programmatically update a Youtube playlist using **nodejs**. In theory, this is possible using the [Google API and jsonc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Add_Favorite_Video).

As I want to do this without user interaction I have been battling with using a **Google API [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)** on nodejs server.

Notice there is no **API Client Library** for Javascript listed on this page.

I then stumbled across this message in the Google documentation for using [Service Accounts with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#instantiate_a_drive_service_object):

> For security reasons service accounts are not supported in client-side Javascript. Service accounts for server-side Javascript is not yet supported.

Is this saying that what I want to achieve is not possible? **I cannot use a Service Account on a NodeJS server to make changes to a playlist without user interaction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Not yet supported. There have been security problems with service accounts.  This may become possible in the future.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

Since yet there is no integration via Javascript for security reasons , you maybe want to try implementing this library.

https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt